# pager is not working in datatables when data coming dynamically in tbody

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable, pagination

Hello I have created data table by using bootstrap data table plugin, In static data pagination working
properly but when the records coming dynamically tbody then pagination not working. and when put data staticlly it pagination starts working. how to solve this issue.

I am using this data table plugin  -- https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap

Html

```
<table id="example" class="display table table-bordered example-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 5%;" class="text-center">#</th>
                                        <th>mydata</th>
                                        <th>mydata</th>
                                        <th>mydata</th>
                                        <th>mydata</th>
                                        <th>mydata</th>
                                        <th>mydata</th>
                                        <th>mydata</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="tBody" runat="server">

                                       Heres data coming dynamically 
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

i am adding data dynamically in this manner
this code in aspx page

```
 <tbody id="tBody" runat="server"> </tbody>
and this me .cs page code
public static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt, string TabValue)
        {
            int count = 1;
            string html = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td class=\"text-center\">" + count + "</td>";
                html += "<td>2019</td>";
                html += "<td>Rabi</td>";
                html += "<td>Kanataka</td>";
                html += "<td>Bagalkote</td>";
                html += "<td>Grape</td>";
        html += "<td>21/09/2019</td>";
                
                html += "<td class=\"text-center\"><span class=\"actionEdit\">";
                html += "<i class=\"fa fa-pencil gototermsheet\"  title=\"Edit\" onclick=\"return EditRecord('" + dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "')\"></i> ";
                html += "<i class=\"fa fa-trash\" title=\"Delete\" onclick=\"return DeleteRecord('" + dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "')\"></i> ";
                html += "</span>";
                html += "</td>";
                
                html += "</tr>";
                count++;
            }
            htmltable = html;
            return html;
        }
```

and in my jquery ajax method
i am binding

```
$("#tBody").html(info.htmlData);
```

in success part

Comment: Could you share how you are populating your tbody dynamically and also you jQuery DataTable initialization, please?

Comment: @Sagnalrac I have added in question